# Will a bloom filter produce false negatives if it becomes full?

Tags: hash

Does the "no false negative" property hold if a bloom filter becomes full?
I tried playing with [this](https://llimllib.github.io/bloomfilter-tutorial/) interactive example but it only gives the false positive probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the "no false negative" property hold if a bloom filter becomes full?

Yes, it will still hold - if the value $X$ has been stored in a bloom filter, then a query on $X$ will always return yes.  For example, if the value $X$ corresponds to the bits $(3, 14, 159)$, then on storing, those bits will be set in the filter (and they will never be cleared) - a latter query on $X$ will check the bits $(3, 14, 159)$, and will see that all three are set.  This holds true no matter how many other values are also stored within the bloom filter.

If the 'bloom filter' is full, that is, all bits in the bloom filter are set, then any query will return 'yes' - hence, there are no false negatives (but there are a huge number of false positives)